# How to define a constant using Clang that can be used in C source files?

Tags: c++, c, clang

How can I define a constant (e.g. `#define`) on the command-line using `clang` that can be accessed in the compiled C source files?

I've seen C source code like the following, where `LEVELNAME` is defined nowhere in the sources, so it has to be specified at compile-time somehow:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://example.com"
```

Comment: `-DBANNER="some level name"` though you'll also want to stringify the definition like `#LEVELNAME`

Comment: Is it possible to set `LEVELNAME` to e.g. `folder/filename`? Do you know how? @kmdreko